# Sybase equivalent for Oracle query

Tags: oracle, join, left-join, inner-join, sybase

I am trying to convert a sybase query to equivalent oracle query in oracle sql developer.

Sybase query:

```
SELECT OdpdInfo.origLocCd, OdpdInfo.destLocCd, OdpdInfo.prodOffset, Act.locCd, Act.actCd, NRLL.seq, Lane.mandatory24HrDelay, Lane.mandatoryMode, 
ONRL.effDaysL, NR.mvPercent, NR.routingType, NR.priority, Transit.locCd, Transit.seq, Transit.mandatoryFlag, ProductType.prodType, ProductType.hndlCd, 
NR.networkRtgId, OdpdInfo.odpdKey 
FROM OdpdInfo, OdpdNetworkRtgLink ONRL, NetworkRtg NR, Activity Act, Transit, NetworkRtgLaneLink NRLL, Lane, ProductType 
WHERE OdpdInfo.odpdKey = ONRL.odpdKey 
AND ONRL.networkRtgId = NR.networkRtgId 
AND NR.networkRtgId = NRLL.networkRtgId 
AND NRLL.laneId = Lane.laneId
-- outer join here
AND Lane.laneId *= Transit.laneId
AND Act.activityId = Lane.destActivityId 
AND OdpdInfo.prodOffset = ProductType.prodOffset 
AND Transit.grpKey < 2
```

Oracle query:

```
SELECT Odpd_Info.orig_Loc_Cd, Odpd_Info.dest_Loc_Cd, Odpd_Info.prod_Offset, Act.loc_Cd, Act.act_Cd, NRLL.seq, Lane.mandatory_24_Hr_Delay, 
Lane.mandatory_Mode, ONRL.eff_Days_L, NR.mv_Percent, NR.routing_Type, NR.priority, Transit.loc_Cd, Transit.seq, Transit.mandatory_Flag, Product_Type.prod_Type, 
Product_Type.hndl_Cd, NR.network_Rtg_Id, Odpd_Info.odpd_Key 
FROM Odpd_Info, Odpd_Network_Rtg_Link ONRL, Network_Rtg NR, Activity Act, Transit, 
Network_Rtg_Lane_Link NRLL, Lane, Product_Type 
WHERE Odpd_Info.odpd_Key = ONRL.odpd_Key 
AND ONRL.network_Rtg_Id = NR.network_Rtg_Id 
AND NR.network_Rtg_Id = NRLL.network_Rtg_Id 
AND NRLL.lane_Id = Lane.lane_Id 
-- outer join here
AND Lane.lane_Id (+)= Transit.lane_Id 
AND Act.activity_Id = Lane.dest_Activity_Id 
AND Odpd_Info.prod_Offset = Product_Type.prod_Offset 
AND Transit.grp_Key < 2 
AND Odpd_Info.common_case_oid = 1 
AND ONRL.common_case_oid = 1 
AND NR.common_case_oid = 1 
AND Act.common_case_oid = 1 
AND Transit.common_case_oid = 1 
AND NRLL.common_case_oid = 1 
AND Lane.common_case_oid = 1 
AND Product_Type.common_case_oid = 1
```

But I am not getting an exact count in oracle as that of sybase. I need help to fix this oracle query to get the expected output.

Comment: You have more filter conditions in oracle query than sybase query. Hence you are getting incorrect count.

Comment: If you change the Oracle query to proper ANSI-92 format and use 'outer join' the exact same SQL should also run on Sybase. As Ankit has indicated the two queries are not the same at present for the search arguments (where clause).

Comment: We are using common_case_oid value to indicate a particular case that indicates a plan period in oracle but in sybase we have table data seperately for each plan period. So we need to include this value while converting each and every query from Sybase to Oracle.

Comment: I also tried using left outer join for Lane and Transit tables but still I am not getting the exact result.

Comment: how did you get the data into Oracle? how did you verify the datasets (number of rows, contents of each column) are 100% identical between Sybase and Oracle?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: AND Lane.lane_Id =(+) Transit.lane_Id

Answer (score 0):

The Sybase query is a straightforward query, it just uses old-style join and old style outer join. You can convert those to ANSI joins and the query should procuce same results:

```
SELECT 
  oi.origLocCd, 
  oi.destLocCd, 
  oi.prodOffset, 
  Act.locCd, 
  Act.actCd, 
  NRLL.seq, 
  l.mandatory24HrDelay, 
  l.mandatoryMode, 
  ONRL.effDaysL, 
  NR.mvPercent, 
  NR.routingType, 
  NR.priority, 
  t.locCd, 
  t.seq, 
  t.mandatoryFlag, 
  pt.prodType, 
  pt.hndlCd, 
  NR.networkRtgId, 
  oi.odpdKey 
FROM OdpdInfo oi
  JOIN OdpdNetworkRtgLink on ONRL.odpdKey=oi.odpdKey
  JOIN ProductType pt on pt.prodOffset=oi.prodOffset
  JOIN NetworkRtg NR on NR.networkRtgId=ONRL.networkRtgId
  JOIN NetworkRtgLaneLink NRLL on NRLL.networkRtgId=NR.networkRtgId
  JOIN Lane l on l.laneId=NRLL.laneId
  JOIN Activity Act on Act.activityId=l.destActivityId 
  LEFT JOIN Transit t on t.laneId=NRLL.laneId and t.grpKey < 2
```